# TypedFactoryFacility: how do i initialize an object with an inline parameter?

Tags: castle-windsor

How can i produce the same output as specified below using the TypedFactoryFacility?

```
public class Something    
{
    public void Initialize(Whatever instance) {}
}

public interface ISomethingFactory
{
    Something Create(Whatever instance);
}

internal class SomethingFactory : ISomethingFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public SomethingFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public Something Create(Whatever instance)
    {
        Something item = _container.Resolve<Something>();
        item.Initialize(instance);
        return item;
    }
}
```

So I want to replace the manual factory with a proxy-generated ITypedFactoryFacility, but I cant find a way to invoke something on the resolved component after creation. I looked at commission-concerns, but you don't have a reference to the CreationContext from a custom commision concern so that won't work. I could of course move the dependency to the ctor and provide an ctor override, but I think properties are good when you want to convey non-optional dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to invoke stuff on the instance upon creation - Windsor will automagically inject stuff *when the name of the parameter in the factory method signature matches something that can be injected* - be it constructor paramaters or public properties... short example (using a public property):

```
interface ISomeFactory
{
    Something CreateSomething(object dataSource);
}

class Something
{
    public object DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

Given that these are registered like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeFactory>().AsFactory(),
                   Component.For<Something>().Lifestyle.Transient)
```

you can resolve instances of `Something` like this:

```
var aintThatSomething = someFactory.CreateSomething(new [] {"ZOMG!", "w00t!"});
```

Remember that if something inside the burden associated with the instance of `Something` requires decommissioning, you need to provide an appropriate `Release` method on the factory as well.

Comment: If its a constructor argument yes, but what if I want to provide it through something else than the constructor? As you see in my example, I am explicitly not specifying a constructor dependency on the ViewModel class

Comment: I changed the example to show how an object can be passed to the factory, allowing it to be set on a public property upon resolution... is that more like what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Nice, did not know that the TypedFactoryFacility was that smart about properties. I've updated my example to show my intent more clearly. Sorry for the unclear example, but at least I learned something new :-)